# Verb chaining: ambiguous or not? ("Please wait until installation finishes to continue")

Tags: verbs, ambiguity

Every time I see this message in [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/studio) (a free google app) I ask myself whether it is proper English or not?

> ***Please wait until the installation finishes to continue***

While it is definitely grammatically correct English, it is ambiguous because **continue** can refer to both **wait** and **finishes**, or is it just me?

I am tempted to link **to continue** with **finishes** primarily because of their proximity, and I might be able to conceptualize as something *finishes to continue* which would be the same as *to stop* or *to complete*. If alternative interpretations of a sentence do not make much sense does it mean that a statement is not ambiguous?

[image: Android Studio download progress message]

Comment: It's not ambiguous: *finish* does not take infinitival complements, so *to continue* cannot be parsed as a complement to *finish*. It is however awkward, because a) you have to track back to find the verb the infinitival does complement and b) *wait to continue* is itself not very felicitous. "Please wait ... before continuing" might be a little better. I'd say "Please don't continue until the installation finishes".

Comment: This is known as a [garden path sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence). In this particular case, the intended meaning comes across fairly clearly.

Comment: "Continue" doesn't refer to anything. It has a meaning similar to "proceed", so its an intransitive verb here, hence no complement.

Comment: @StoneyB: In fact there is no option to continue in the dialog, as can be seen from the screenshot. Using the _Background_ button can be seen as a way to continue, but then again the message is not specific as to what exactly the user might want to continue doing.

Comment: Apparently I wasn't the only one who saw it as ambiguous: google changed the message to _`Please wait until the installation finishes.`_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please wait until the installation finishes to continue

This is not the best English, but is not terribly ambiguous.
Using the same words, it could have been written:

> To continue, please wait until the installation finishes

Of course a better way would be:

> Please wait until the instillation finishes before continuing.

More awkward than ambiguous, we often see sentences such as the one in question in technical material. However awkward, the three implied actions (*wait, finishes and continue*) are in the correct order to corectly follow the instructions.